# Issues with Sharing Precompiled Header

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers

I know this has been asked a hundred times but I can't seem to get my projects working.
I have two projects, both are static libraries (.lib). One project is my Core Engine project which has a precompiled header, my other project is a Input Manager project which uses my Core Engine so my initial problem is that if I don't setup my Input Manager project with a precompiled header, all of the Core Engine files have compiler errors for missing includes.
So I've been trying to setup my Input Manager to use the precompiled header from the Core Engine project and I'll go over how I have it setup.

My Core Engine project is setup how you'd normally setup a precompiled header and that all works.
On the Core Engine project itself

[image: Core Engine Project PCH Settings]

My PrecompiledHeader.cpp file uses these settings.

[image: PrecompiledHeader.cpp settings]

My Input Manager on the other hand is what I think is giving me the trouble and I've tried a whole bunch of different settings and I haven't gotten anywhere with it. This is how my Input Manager project is setup.

[image]

So it points to the Core Engine's .pch file.
Using some answers I found online, I also copy over the Core Engine's .pdb and .idb files like so.

[image]

That's working, those two .pdb and .idb files are getting copied over.
I also added the Core Engine's folder to the Additional Include Directories and I think that's about all I should have to do based on everything I've read online but still can't get it to work.

My Input Manager project right now just has two files, InputManager.h and InputManager.cpp and I've tried including and not include PrecompiledHeader.h at the top of InputManager.cpp. No matter what I try, I just get this error from the Input Manager project.

```
unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "PrecompiledHeader.h"' to your source?
```

If anyone has any insight on how to make this work or even a better solution, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're supposed to use a different precompiled header per project. Also how did you include it?

Comment: From what I've read online, sharing a precompiled header across projects is doable, just seems tricky. I tried just adding PrecompiledHeader.cpp and PrecompiledHeader.h to my Input Manager project also and just having that make it's own .pch for my Input Manager project but didn't have luck with that either.
When I say I included the PrecompiledHeader.h at the top of InputManager.cpp, I just added
#include "PrecompiledHeader.h"
at the top

Answer (score 0):

At present, there is another way to achieve shared precompiled headers by building a SharedPCH. You could refer to [Microsoft Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/shared-pch-usage-sample-in-visual-studio/) for more information. Here is the article.

When ConsoleApplication projects reference the SharedPCH one, the build will automatically link the SharedPCH’s static lib, but several project properties need to be changed as well.

[image]
C/C++ Additional Include Directories (/I) should contain the shared stdafx.h directory
C/C++ Precompiled Header Output File (/Fp) should be set to the shared pch file (produced by SharedPCH project)
If your projects are compiled with /Zi or /ZI (see more info about those switches at the end), the projects which use the shared pch need to copy the .pdb and .idb files produced by the shared pch project to their specific locations so the final pdb files contains pch symbols.
As those properties need to be changed similarly for all projects, I created the SharedPCH.props and CustomBuildStep.props files and imported them to my projects using the Property Manager tool window.

SharedPch.props helps with #1 and #2 and is imported in all projects. CustomBuildStep.props helps with #3 and is imported to consuming pch projects, but not to the producing one. If your projects are using /Z7, you don’t need CustomBuildStep.props.

[image]

In SharedPch.props, I defined properties for shared pch, pdb and idb files locations:

[image]

Adjusted C/C++ ‘Additional Include Directories’ and ‘Precompiled Header Output File’ properties:

[image]

[image]

In CustomBuildStep.props I defined Custom Build Step to run before ClCompile target and copy the shared pch .pdb and .idb files if they are newer than the project’s .pdb and .idb files. Note that we are talking about compiler intermediate pdb file here and not the final one produced by the linker.

If all files in the project are using one pch, that’s all we need to do, since when the pch is changed, all other files need to be recompiled as well, so at the end of the build we’ll have full pdb and idb files.

If your project uses more than one pch or contains files that are not using pch at all, you’ll need to change pdb file location (/Fd) for those files, so that it is not overridden by the shared pch pdb.

[image]

I used the command line property editor to define the commands. Each ‘xcopy’ command should be on its own line:

[image]